# How can I listen to new receive transfer?

Tags: api, javascript

I want to listen to new transfers and get the hash and amount.
How can I?
Also, Can I get list transfers of account like this url?
https://westend.subscan.io/account/5D8JvKv1yL8ZPN9xxNbQiRxX14KvpiP8UJcDys1ouDnKpczx
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest splitting your questions into two - it is somewhat difficult to answer 2 completely different questions coherently in one.

First off, you mention "hash" - be aware that transaction hashes in Substrate are non-unique. Here are some older [questions that deal with this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/get-transaction-by-hash). You also mentioned JS in your tags, so the [FAQ entry](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/FAQ#which-api-can-i-use-to-query-by-transaction-hash) could be useful, along with the [wiki entry for unique identifiers](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-protocol-info#unique-identifiers-for-extrinsics)

To listen for transfers, your best approach is to [listen to events](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2792/how-to-confirm-payment-from-specific-address/2793#2793) or indeed scan the blocks as the answer suggests.

For retrieving a list of transactions by account, [here is a previous question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/get-account-transactions-using-substrate-api/1496#1496) that answers this in detail with specific tools that you can use.